# How to view sparse matrix as np array when loading from npy files?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, sparse-matrix, numpy-ndarray

I have some `npy` files and I want to load them as normal arrays to see their contents, usually, when I use `np.load()` it would give me nd-arrays directly, but for this file, I have to set `allow_pickle=True` to get the loading work first, then when I print it, I get lines (in the image below) instead of arrays. I tried the `d[()]` but it gives the exact same output as `print(d)`.
Is there any way I could load them as normal nd-arrays? I'm using Python 3 on Jupiter notebook.

[image]

Comment: How was this file created?  What you show is an array, object dtype, containing many sparse matrices.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how it was created, it's supposed to store some adjacent matrices. @hpaulj

Comment: For each matrix you have to use `toarray()` method to see it full.